# How to organize assets in a game?

Tags: game-development

I am currently proramming a game and was wondering what was the best way to store paths to assets.

By that I mean :
I have a directory

```
assets/
    icons/
       ...
    images/
       ...
Etc
```

Where to search for assets. Thus in my code I have lines such as

```
let image = new Image("assets/icons/my_icon.png")
```

(Javascript but it doesn't matter)

But I don't find elegant (nor practital) to have such litteral paths scattered around, and I was wondering what was the "usual" way to do this.
Passing around a big object with all the paths stored in doesn't seem that good neither, and it can be tiresome to write everywhere `myFunction(...params, THE_BIG_OBJECT)`...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am using Unity for game dev, but the general idea applies to your case as well. I am using this structure, just fit it to your needs:

```
Assets
|_Scripts
    |_System1
    |_System2
    |_System3
|_Sprites
    |_Icons
    |_UI
    |_etc.
|_Models
|_etc.
```

Regarding the paths, tho I am not using JS, maybe save the paths in variables, and then when referencing a specific asset you can write:

```
let iconsPath = "/Assets/Sprites/Icons"
let image = new Image("${iconPath}/my_icon.png")
```

Comment: I'm gonna do that. Thanks !